# multer rename doesn't work with filename opts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I have no clue why this doesn't work. The upload is working, the naming has long string like `04504a8b6c715f933110c8c970a8f6ad`. What I want it the filename + the extension.

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({
    dest: 'public/uploads',
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        switch (file.mimetype) {
            case 'image/jpeg':
                ext = '.jpeg';
                break;
            case 'image/png':
                ext = '.png';
                break;
        }
        cb(null, file.originalname + ext);
    }

});

router.post('/upload_photo', upload.any(), function(req, res, next) {
//callback
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to just upload .jpeg and .png?

Try replacing `cb(null, file.originalname + ext);`
with `cb(null, file.originalname);` and see if it still gives you the random string.